# Let finish an android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created an AlarmManager to close my main activity at a certain time. It uses the CLEAR_TOP flag to close the main activity. My problem is that if the main activity is doing something important, I must let it finish its work.

I put the code in the `onDestroy()` method, but I read in the Android documentation to use instead  `onPause()` or `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)`. The problem is that I don't get how can I let my activity finish its work correctly with these methods.

Comment: What kind of work that is? Maybe you should put in an asynctask?

Comment: If you have a real big task try to use `service`

Comment: Rather than forcing your activity to go away, could you instead send it an Intent that tells it that it needs to go away?  Then the Activity could clean itself up and quit when it is done.

Comment: The problem is that i have no reference to the main activity. So the last activity starts with the clear flag and i can't finish the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `isFinishing()` insed of `onPause()` and it works.